# Iconslider in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, branding

hi i want to put a slider for our link icons in which stop after one move for 1 second and move again exactly like below image from site https://www.nestle.ch/de
[image]

as you see I want tow arrey key in both sides and an stop after each automatic move do we need any special jquery?
best regards

Answer (score 0):

In the SharePoint Appstore you can find the App "Bright Banner".
You can configure the slider as you like.

Link to SharePoint Store: [Bright Banner | Office Store](https://store.office.com/bright-banner-WA104046813.aspx?assetid=WA104046813&sourcecorrid=c0267d49-10c9-4334-bfc7-a4f762605311&searchapppos=0)

I am using this App in SharePoint 2016, but it should aswell work in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: thank you but I want to know if there is any way to implement it myself or if there is any solutions and the app is for banner I want for link icons